# Querying Two Tables Based on a Third that Relates Them

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create a query based on two tables and a third linking table shown below.

```
Letter_DBID   Letter_ID  
-------        ----- 
  1             Alpha  
  2             Beta  
  3             Delta    


Fruit_DBID      Fruit_ID 
-------          -----
  1             Apples  
  2             Oranges   
  3             Bananas


Linking table:
Letter_ID      Fruit_ID
-------         -----
 Alpha          Oranges
 Delta          Bananas
 Beta           Apples
 Alpha          Bananas
```

The DBIDs are unique primary keys, but the IDs are non-unique.  I want to create a view based on these three tables that displays how the unique DBIDs relate to eachother.  Something like this:

```
Letter_DBID   Fruit_DBID  
-------        -----  
  1            2  
  3            3  
  2            1    
  1            3
```

Where the DBIDs in the same row correspond to the IDs in the linking table.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to write this query or point me in the right direction?
I am using MS Access 2010
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it with two LEFT JOINS :

```
 SELECT Letter_DBID ,  Fruit_DBID FROM linking
 left join table2 on table2.`Fruit_ID` = linking.`Fruit_ID`
 left join table1 on table1.`Letter_ID` = linking.`Letter_ID`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9a6d/12)

Comment: Very helpful, `SELECT Letters.Letter_DBID ,  Fruits.Fruit_DBID FROM (linking left join Fruits on Fruits.Fruit_ID = linking.Fruit_ID)
left join Letters on Letters.Letter_ID = linking.Letter_ID;`  Ended up doing the trick!

Answer (score 0):

As the IDs aren't unique, how are you wanting to handle the overlap?
For instance, say we add
    FRUIT_DBID: 4   FRUIT_ID: Apples
Do you want both, or just one to show up in the final view?
(from your example data)
    Letter_DBID   Fruit_DBID
    -------        -----
      2              1
      2              4

If you want just one, I don't think there is a way from the non-unique data. If both are acceptable, I'd do something like

```
SELECT
    le.Letter_DBID, 
    f.Fruit_DBID

FROM
    (Letters le LEFT JOIN Linking li
    ON le.Letter_ID = li.Letter_ID)
    LEFT JOIN Fruits f
    ON f.Fruit_ID=li.Fruit_ID
```